# How to make tcl https work with mitmproxy?

Tags: http, ssl, tcl, mitmproxy

I am trying to make HTTPS calls with [Tcl](https://www.tcl-lang.org) using the [http](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/http.htm) and [tls](https://core.tcl.tk/tcltls/home) modules, and I would like to view the calls themselves with [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org).

I first installed mitmproxy, installed its certificates and verified that it is working fine by pointing Firefox to use the proxy at localhost:8080. I can view all the https calls in mitmproxy and can see the right responses in the browser.

I am now trying to get the following code to work properly with mitmproxy:

```
package require http
package require tls

http::register https 443 tls::socket

http::config -proxyhost localhost
http::config -proxyport 8080

set token [http::geturl "https://google.com"]
set resp [http::data $token]
http::cleanup $token
puts $resp

http::unregister https
```

If I do not have two `http::config` lines to set up the proxy, the script works fine. However, if I do have those two lines, I get the follow:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        <p>ProtocolException(&#x27;Cannot connect to server, no server address given.&#x27;)</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The mitmproxy shows me a similar error in the UI.

I've also tried to `export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080/` and the permutations of changing `http` for `https` and then do the following:

```
package require http
package require tls
package require autoproxy

autoproxy::init
http::register https 443 autoproxy::tls_socket
set tok [http::geturl https://google.com/]
set data [http::data $tok]
puts $data
```

and I get a similar response:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        <p>TlsProtocolException(&quot;Cannot establish TLS with google.com:443 (sni: None): TlsException(&#x27;Cannot validate certificate hostname without SNI&#x27;)&quot;)</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I have to believe that I am not using tcl to send something in the request that I should be, but I am at a loss as to what that is. How do I modify the above code so that it works properly with this proxy server?

Comment: The 502 in your second attempt is not related to your proxy setup, but the proxy tells you that the Google server did not permit a TLS connection without SNI. How did you obtain TclTLS? Which version? Did you build against OpenSSL/ LibreSSL supporting SNI?

Comment: Or: How do you run mitmproxy exactly? If you use a TclTLS w/o SNI, you will have to start as `mitmproxy --insecure` (see https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/1846)

Comment: The first 502 smells like you have not set up IP forwarding. Are you trying to run `mitmproxy` in transparent mode? Did you follow all prerequisites document at https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/?